# How can I use run instead of communicate when providing text on stdin?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, cmd, adb

trying to figure out how to do this:

```py
command = f"adb -s {i} shell"
proc = Popen(command, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
out, err = proc.communicate(f'dumpsys package {app_name} | grep version'.encode('utf-8'))
```

but in this:

```py
command = f"adb -s {i} shell"
proc = run(command, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
out, err  = run(f'dumpsys package {app_name} | grep version', shell=True, text=True, stdin=proc.stdout )
```

The idea is to make a command which require input of some kind( for example(entering shell)) and afterwards inserting another command to shell.
I've found a way online with communicate, But I wonder how to do it with run() func.
Thanks!

Comment: Please read [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Spaces should be used around `=` only in assignments, not it keyword parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to call `run` once -- pass the remote command in the `input` argument (and don't use `shell=True` in places where you don't need it).

```
import subprocess, shlex
proc = subprocess.run(['adb', '-s', i, 'shell'],
                      capture_output=True,
                      input=f'dumpsys package {shlex.quote(app_name)} | grep version')
```

`shlex.quote` prevents an app name that contains `$(...)`, `;`, etc from running unwanted commands on your device.